How can I filter an aggregate using an integer variable?
I have an aggregate that I want the user to be able to filter by minimum and maximum values of a variable tied to an input field. If the field is empty, no filtering should happen. If it has a number, then filter by showing only records where a field has at least the value in the variable. I've tried the following, but even when the input field is empty, and therefore the variable is empty, no records get returned.
(minBalance <> "")
  and (minBalance > 0)
  and (TextToInteger(Table.Balance) > minBalance)

Adding this filter to the aggregate removes all records from the search. Removing it successfully shows the records expected. How can I use a field to filter numeric data based on minimum (and, eventually, maximum) values entered by the user?

If the input field is empty, the expression needs to return true. So you need to invert the condition and use or.  You may also need to convert the input to integer, just like Table.Balance.
(minBalance = "") or (TextToInteger(Table.Balance) > minBalance)


Balance is a text field because of trouble with getting data from a legacy system if we make it an integer. minBalance was an integer, but I converted it to text to experiment (casting to an integer with the same func used on the Balance field), but using the logic you have, while showing records when the field is empty, doesn't filter when I enter a value that should obviously exclude records with a lower value.

Looks like the query wasn't being resubmitted and this may work. Have to fix the other problem first.

Maybe you need > TextToInteger(minBalance). I don't use OutSystems, I was guessing it would coerce automatically, since you didn't convert in your query.

In Outsystems comparison in expressions is done with a single = instead of dubbel one. I added this change ot your answer.
